# Compose Enhanser is not a function

Tags: reactjs

When I run my react app it display this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: composeEnhancers is not a function

this is my store code

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from "redux";

import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import logger from "redux-logger";
import rootReduer from "./root-Reducer";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";

let middlewares;
let composeEnhancers;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  const composeEnhancers =
  window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__'] || compose;
  middlewares = [thunk, logger];
} else {
  middlewares = [thunk];
  composeEnhancers = compose;
}

// hide action with state in console.log in deplyment app.
export const store = createStore(
  rootReduer,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middlewares))
);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have re-declared `composeEnhancers` inside the first `if` block. Remove the re-declared `const` before `componseEnhancers`. The could would look like

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  composeEnhancers = window['__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__'] || compose;
  middlewares = [thunk, logger];
  //... other codes
```